# getting DIV ID erroneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that selects a page element like a div and changes it's color through a color picker plugin.. however when I click on a div, it reads the ID of the first div only..and also only changes the same div. even I click on another div, it keeps reading the first div in the body. any suggestions on how to deal with it? here's the code. :D

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var elementTag;
var divID;
    $("#modalPicker").dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        height: 299,
        width: 247,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function(){
        $('#picker').farbtastic(function(color) {
            $("#"+divID).css("background-color", color);
        });
        }

    });

    $("BODY").click(function(event){

        elementTag = event.target.nodeName;
        alert(elementTag);
        if($(""+elementTag).attr('id') != undefined)
        {
            divID = $(""+elementTag).attr('id');
            //divID = this.id;
            alert(divID);
            $(this).removeClass();
            $("#modalPicker").dialog("open");
        }
        else if($(""+elementTag).attr('id') == undefined)
        {
            alert("no ID for this element!");
        }
    });


});
</script>

 <body style="border:#00CCFF; border-bottom-style:dashed">


<div id="HEADER" style="size: 500px">HEADER</div>

<div id="BODY" style="height:700 px; width:1024; border: 20 px">BODY</div>

<div id="FOOTER" style="height: 400 px; width: 500 px; border-bottom-color:#000000">FOOTER</div>

<span> SIMON </span>

<li> here
    <ul>SIMON</ul>
</li>   

<div id="modalPicker">
    <div id="picker"></div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: add your html for the page so we can see it too

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple divs with the same ID. That won't work,  IDs are supposed to be unique, use classes instead.

Comment: Are you saying with have divs that have the same ID? Also, posting your HTML might help.

Comment: every div has a unique ID. :D I shall edit the post.. my apologies. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always getting the first DIV in your html. `element.target.nodeName` will return DIV (if you click in a DIV) and then you're just getting the Jquery object of that first div.

I think you need to change the way your're creating the jquery DIV as

```
var div = $(event.target)
var divID = div.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a tag name (`div`, `input`, etc) to the jQuery function as a selector, which will return a set containing all elements that have that tag - so, in this case, all `<div>` elements on the page. Calling functions such as `val()` or `attr()` that return, rather than set, values only acts on the first element in the set returned.

So, when you click on **any** div in your code, it gets a set of all `<div>` elements, but then gets the ID of the first element that matched (the first `<div>`) and then that gets used inside the `dialog()` function called later on.

Change your code to access the `id` attribute of the element that was clicked on, rather than using a tag selector like you are now, like so:

```
$("BODY").click(function(event){
    var $id = $(event.target).attr('id');
    if($id != undefined)
    {
        divID = $id;
        alert(divID);
        $(this).removeClass();
        $("#modalPicker").dialog("open");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no ID for this element!");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your code doesn't seem to work. I've tried it..:(

Comment: @user1196490 I've edited my answer - you'll need to use `event.target` rather than `this` to access the element that originally triggered the click event, since it bubbles up to the `<body>` element and then triggers that callback. In that case, `this` refers to the `<body>` element, rather than the `<div>` that was clicked on.

Comment: i also want to check if what I clicked is the body of the page or the whole html page.. because if the user clicks on divs they can only change color while if they click on a body/background.. they can change the color or image background.

Answer (score 1):

Nice explanation from Anthony, another option you have is to get the id directly from the event.target object.  http://jsfiddle.net/gaboesquivel/XDUM2/

I also added within your function 'var' to the variable definition ('globals are evil'), 
stopPropagation and preventDefault calls

Comment: +1 for making a good point - there's really no need to wrap it in a jQuery object to access the `id` of the element. And, normally, I wouldn't do this myself - though sometimes I still do.